# How to get response status code in angular 1.5.6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying a lot of aproaches, some of them:

```
   $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '/Url'}).then(function successCallback(response) {
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
      });

    var req = {
        method: 'GET',
        interceptor: {
            response: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
                var result = response.resource;
                result.$status = response.status;
                return result;
            }
        },
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': token
        }
    }

    $http(req).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data, status, headers, config);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(data, status, headers, config);
    });
```

And a lot of others with no result, so I really need help !!!
I would grateful for any help

Comment: You need to set up the interceptor in the config method. See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: can you add plunker example, please? cos i was trying to do it with no result

Comment: If the provided `url` is not valid then your 'response' function will never be called, and so you will never see the `console.log(...)` written in your `response` function.

Answer (score 0):

The first approach looks close to what you need.

```
function successCallback(response) {
  console.log('status code: ', response.status);
}
```

Currently the callback is empty so we are accessing response object and logging status code from it.

Comment: You will have to use correct URL in your example. What's the URL you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The first way is the more direct way of doing but I'm pretty sure that the response functions should be anonymous. Putting a console.log() in both will help.

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/Url'
  }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.status);
  }, function(response) {
      console.log(response.status);
  });
```

If that doesn't work just put the console.log(response) in both to see what it gets you.

Comment: What does the console.log output when you do it this way? Postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) is also a helpful tool for debugging http requests. If you request or endpoint isn't set up right, then that could be a reason why you can't get a status code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use httpinterceptor if you want to track all your requests :

```
myModule.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q) {

    return {
        response: function (response) {
            // do something with success response
            // status in response.status
            return response;
        },
        responseError: function (response) {
            // do something with error response
            // status in response.status
            return $q.reject(response);
        }
    };

});

myModule.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
});
```